# Possible to Bake a ColorRamp with Geometry?

Tags: materials, texture-baking

So I have a ColorRamp hooked up to the position's Z axis as a factor, such that when viewing it I get a gradient from top to bottom. However, when I try to bake it, I'll usually get two colors in the texture.
[image]